# Rails/Postgres query Hstore for presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgresql-9.2, hstore

I have some HStore columns in my Rails app. Looking around the Posgresql documentation and [some blog posts](http://codeloveandboards.com/blog/2014/07/16/rails-and-prostgresql-hstore-simple-use-case/), I've discovered that, given an HStore value that is a hash like this:

```
{ some_key: 'value' }
```

I can query the columns like so:

```
Model.where("the_hstore_column -> 'some_key' = 'value'")
```

There are a bunch of issues with this as a sufficient querying tool, however:

1. It really only makes sense for super simple values. If the value is
   itself a hash or something, I have no idea how to search for it
   effectively, if I don't know all its contents. (Even if I did, I'd
   have to turn them all to stringified JSON or something).
2. It isn't helpful (at least, I can't make it helpful) for doing
   queries for the presence or non-presence of the column's content (or
   the content of any key under the column).

In other words (in pseudo-sql), I'd love to be able to do this:

```
Model.where("the_hstore_column = {}")
Model.where.not("the_hstore_column = {}")
```

Or:

```
Model.where("the_hstore_column -> 'some_key' = NULL")
Model.where.not("the_hstore_column -> 'some_key' = NULL")
```

Or best yet, given an HStore of value `{ some_key: { sub_key: 'value' } }`:

```
Model.where("the_hstore_column -> 'some_key' INCLUDES (?)", 'sub_key')
Model.where.not("the_hstore_column -> 'some_key' INCLUDES (?)", 'sub_key')
```

These appear not to be working, but for the life of me, I can't find great information on how to conduct these queries. Does anyone know how to write them, or where I could look for better information?

**UPDATE** After more looking around, I found [this post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=13), which looked promising, but I can't get the code to actually work. For example `Model.where("the_hstore_column ? :key", key: 'some_key')` is returning an empty relation, even if there are many `Model` objects with `some_key` in `the_hstore_column`.

**As requested by Andrius Buivydas**, I'm pasting the relevant portion of my model below. It's relatively brief, because I decided to abstract out the Hstore-accessing into a module I wrote, essentially turning it into a hash store (which I though, apparently incorrectly, was its whole purpose). I tried using the built-in [`store_accessor`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods/store_accessor), but it didn't work to my liking, (didn't seem to help parse saved hashes, for now obvious-seeming reasons) thus the `ActiveRecord::MetaExt::HstoreAccessor` module below. (`ParsedHstore` just takes an HStore string and parses it into a hash).

```
class Place.rb

  include ActiveRecord::MetaExt::HstoreAccessor
  hstore_accessor :hours, :extra

end
```

(In a separate file):

```
module ActiveRecord
  module MetaExt
    module HstoreAccessor

      module ClassMethods

        def hstore_accessor(*symbols)
          symbols.each do |field|
            class_eval do 
              define_method(field) do
                ParsedHstore.new(self[field.to_sym]).hash_value
              end

              define_method("add_to_#{field}!") do |arg|
                self[field.to_sym] = self[field.to_sym].merge(arg)
                send("#{field}_will_change!")
                save
                arg
              end

              define_method("add_to_#{field}") do |arg|
                self[field.to_sym] = self[field.to_sym].merge(arg)
                send("#{field}_will_change!")
                arg
              end

              define_method("remove_from_#{field}") do |arg|
                other = self[field].dup
                other.delete(arg.to_s); other.delete(arg.to_sym)
                self[field.to_sym] = other
                send("#{field}_will_change!")
                self[field.to_sym]
              end

              define_method("remove_from_#{field}!") do |arg|
                other = self[field].dup
                other.delete(arg.to_s); other.delete(arg.to_sym)
                self[field.to_sym] = other
                send("#{field}_will_change!")
                save
                self[field.to_sym]
              end

              define_method("set_#{field}") do |arg|
                self[field.to_sym] = arg
                send("#{field}_will_change!")
                self[field.to_sym]
              end

              define_method("set_#{field}!") do |arg|
                self[field.to_sym] = arg
                send("#{field}_will_change!")
                self[field.to_sym]
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end

      def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is that this lets me easily add/remove values to an HStore field, without having to think about the merging and `_will_change!` logic every time. So I could do this, for example: `Place.first.add_to_extra({ key: 'value'})`.

> Should I have made these fields `json` or `jsonb`? I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here, or, more aptly, trying to turn a horse into a wheel or something.

Also, I may be misunderstanding the query example. I literally tried this query in my database (which has many places with a non-empty `ranking` key under the `extra` field), and turned up with an empty relation:

```
Place.where("extra ? :key", key: 'ranking')
```

> I wouldn't be surprised if I messed this syntax up, as it seems really strange. Wouldn't that replace the `?` with `'ranking'`, turning the query into this?: `Place.where("extra ranking :key")`? Seems weird and emphatically different from any other SQL I've run. Or is it turning to `Place.where("extra ? ranking")`? But `?` is usually for safe injection of variables, no?

Please let me know if something else in my model or elsewhere would be more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It really only makes sense for super simple values. If the value is itself a hash or something, I have no idea how to search for it effectively, if I don't know all its contents.

Postgresql HStore stores key, values pairs that are both strings, only. So you can't store a hash, a nil or something else like an object - they will be converted to the strings.

> Model.where("the_hstore_column ? :key", key: 'some_key')

That should work if everything is defined correctly. Could you paste an extract of the model file with the definition of the hstore column values?

Comment: I pasted what I feel to be the relevant sections of my model above. I never explicitly defined the expected values of the Hstore columns (there are two columns -- `extra` and `hours`). I thought the whole idea behind HStore was that you could store unplanned tree-style data in a SQL database, no?

Comment: Well, no, the idea is that you can store semi-structured text data. From postgresql documentation:

>This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. This can be useful in various scenarios, such as rows with many attributes that are rarely examined, or semi-structured data. Keys and values are simply text strings.

[http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)

Comment: So that makes JSON (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) a better datatype for what I'm doing, right? Just want to make sure I'm not missing something before I run the migration to what seems like a better idea.

Comment: Not sure. With JSON datatype you could store arrays of integers, for example as a value, but if you want to store an object I would suggest to use [serialization](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class). Personally, I use HStore when I want to store a 'dumb' string keys and values pairs and JSON if some of the values are an array (rare situation).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find empty hstore columns is

```
Model.where(hstore_column: ['',nil])
```

OR

```
Model.where("hstore_column='' OR hstore_column IS NULL")
```